# Is the edge operator derived from the short exact sequence of the following chain complexes commutative?

Tags: homological-algebra

[image]
As shown in the figure, $A_i $, $B_i$ and $C_i $on the left are all chain complexes, which make up 3 × 3 short exact sequences. Is the diagram on the right necessarily commutative?

($\partial $ is the homologous edge operator derived from snake lemma)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Could you give some more background for this question, and indicate what you have tried so far? If it's a homework, there's not much point in giving you the full answer directly.

Comment: Thanks, the background is from relative  mayer-vietoris sequence in algebraic topology and the question is from Hatcher P152. @Hanno